# Setting the width of text within <a> tag  works in IE and Chrome but not in Firefox

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, firefox

I want the text "See All used-miscellaneous-lasers" in the div width, but the text emerges out of the div only in Firefox. What is the cause of this issue and how can it be resolved?
Here is my code:

**CSS**

```
div.banner a {
     color: #FFFFFF;
     display: inline-block;
     margin-left: -13px;
     text-decoration: none;
     width: 100%; 
}

 div.banner {
     background: url("banner.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: normal;
     height: 38px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     padding: 18px 24px 50px 69px;
     text-align: left;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     width: 106px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="banner">    
    <a target="_blank" href="http://10.0.0.145/used/b">See All used-miscellaneous-lasers</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause is that Firefox thinks that used-miscellaneous-lasers is one word so it does not want to wrap it onto another line. You can easily fix this by adding a space or `nbsp;` after the -'s.

```
<div class="banner">    
    <a target="_blank" href="http://10.0.0.145/used/b">See All used- miscellaneous- lasers</a>
</div>
```

Otherwise to the div css, you can add `word-wrap: break-word;`; however, the word will not always be broken in a form that is readable.

```
div.banner {
    background: url("banner.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    height: 38px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 18px 24px 50px 69px;
    text-align: left;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    width: 106px;
    word-wrap: break-word; 
}
```

[Live DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/VLdRj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I've added  **overflow:visible;**

```
div.banner {
     background: url("banner.jpg") no-repeat scroll center top transparent;
     font-size: 15px;
     font-weight: normal;
     height: 38px;
     margin-top: 20px;
     padding: 18px 24px 50px 69px;
     text-align: left;
     text-transform: uppercase;
     overflow:visible;
     width: 106px; }
```

Comment: No, it didn't help, it just added a scroll-bar.

Comment: My apologies, it should have been overflow:visible; this forces an element to render outside the containing box.

Comment: Why would he want the text to appear outside of the div?

Comment: Relative positioning. I use it to overlap photo's with a bar as background.